# Knockout checkbox issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a checkbox on which I want to bind a function that does something if the checkbox is checked and something if the checkbox isn't checked.

But the checkbox won't stay checked. It is checked when the function is called, but it gets unchecked after exiting the function. What am I doing wrong?

Here's a sample of what I'm trying to do:
http://jsfiddle.net/GSeFD/

JS:

```
function MyViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.click = function(data,event) {
        if ($('#checkbox').is(':checked')){
            console.log('checked');
        }
        else{
            console.log('unchecked');
        }
    }
}
ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" data-bind="click: $root.click" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a `click` handler you need to `return true` if you want to trigger the default browser event (e.g checking the checkbox)

```
self.click = function(data,event) {
    if ($('#checkbox').is(':checked')){
        console.log('checked');
    }
    else{
        console.log('unchecked');
    }
    return true;
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ZV9DP/)

See also the documentation: [Note 3: Allowing the default click action](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html)

By the way should also consider to use the [`checked` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html) if you are working with check-boxes.